# Java - making objects with key/value pairs?

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

I want to make the following types of objects. This is my higher-level desire that I'd like to figure out in Java:

ListObject(key, String): every key corresponds to a String value; key is a string itself

ListObject(key, String[]): every key corresponds to an array of Strings; key is a string itself

ListObject(key, String, String[]): same deal but with two value fields per key.

How would I make (and use!) objects of this type?

Thanks.

Comment: It's called a "Map"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You seem to need some [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)s rather than `List`s. Check [the Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for Map implementations; the most common is `HashMap`, but there are sorted, concurrent, deterministically iterable implementations etc. available too.

> ListObject: every key corresponds to a String value; key is a string itself

```
Map<String, String>
```

> ListObject: every key corresponds to an array of Strings; key is a string itself

```
Map<String, String[]>
```

(or preferably `Map<String, List<String>>`)

> ListObject: same deal but with two value fields per key.

```
Map<String, UserDefinedClassWithTwoFields>
```

Answer (score 4):

`Map<KeyType,ValueType>` which is implemented by [`HashMap<KeyType, ValueType>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [`TreeMap<KeyType, ValueType>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), among others -- HashMap is unordered and TreeMap is ordered.

Other useful Maps are [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which is like `HashMap` but iterates in insertion order, and [`com.google.common.collect.Maps`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html) in Guava which has a bunch of utility methods, and [`com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) which is an immutable map implementation.

For your key corresponding to an array of strings, you might want to look at a [`Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) which is a map with multiple values for a given key.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Map for this purpose.
The general syntax for Map is:

```
Map<String, SomeObject> = new HashMap<String, SomeObject>();
```

Now there are four kinds of Maps in java:

**HASH MAP** - Use this map when you don't care about the order in which elements are displayed when you iterate over the map.

**HASH TABLE** - Synchronized version of hash map.

**LINKED HASH MAP** - Use this when you care about the insertion order.

**TREE MAP** - Use this when you want custom sort order.

Answer (score 1):

Map are used to create associative arrays in Java.

Map for your first example. Each String key is associated to a String value.

Map for your second example. Values are arrays of String.

For your last example, you have to create you own class with two fields: one a String and one a String[]. Then, create a map that associates String to an object of your type.

Answer (score 0):

Java's `Map` type would most likely do the trick. A `Map<KeyType, ValueType>` stores key-value pairs, so you would have a `Map<String, String>`, a `Map<String, List<String>>`, and a `Map<String, SomePairType>`.

`Map` is just an interface: you have to pick an implementation. `HashMap` and `TreeMap` are your best bets. Both are good, but `TreeMap` will only work with comparable key types.
For keys, since `String` is comparable with other Strings, you could use either map implementation.