# Condensing down multiple IF statements

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm fairly new to Java and I'm trying to make a program that allows me to enter a month, then enter a day. I want it to end if the day within the month is valid (I.e. 28 in February is valid, 29 is invalid). I've made it work, but I've used 12 IF statements for each month, and it looks too messy and like too much code.
Could anyone suggests a better method of condensing this down?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calender {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int month=0;
int day=0;

Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

do {        
System.out.print("Enter a month [1..12]: ");
month=in.nextInt();
//continue;
} while (month > 12);
    //System.out.println ("This is not a valid month.");

do {
System.out.print("Enter a day [1..31]: ");
day=in.nextInt();
} while (day > 31);


if (day > 31 && month == 1) {
    System.out.print("This is not a valid day of the month");
} 
if (day > 31 && month == 3) {
    System.out.print("This is not a valid day of the month");
}
if (day > 31 && month == 5) {
    System.out.print("This is not a valid day of the month");
} 
if (day > 31 && month == 7) {
    System.out.print("This is not a valid day of the month");
}
if (day > 31 && month == 8) {
    System.out.print("This is not a valid day of the month");
} 
if (day > 31 && month == 10) {
    System.out.print("This is not a valid day of the month");
}
if (day > 31 && month == 12) {
    System.out.print("This is not a valid day of the month");
} 
if (day > 30 && month == 4) {
    System.out.print("This is not a valid day of the month");
}
if (day > 30 && month == 6) {
    System.out.print("This is not a valid day of the month");
} 
if (day > 30 && month == 9) {
    System.out.print("This is not a valid day of the month");
}
if (day > 30 && month == 11) {
    System.out.print("This is not a valid day of the month");
} 
if (day > 28 && month == 2) {
    System.out.print("This is not a valid day of the month");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry the final IF statement should be a '2' not a '4'

Comment: You can edit your post to correct mistakes you made in the original.

Comment: Use an array of int that holds the number of days in each each month. Then you only need a single if statement, something like: `if (day > months[month] || day <= 0)`

Comment: Look up `switch-case` statements.

Comment: Or use existing solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528047/checking-the-validity-of-a-date

Comment: This question might be better asked at [SE CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: No, you haven't made it work. This code is buggy for February.

Comment: What about leap years? Without the year you can't validate 29.02.

Comment: @CalumMullen Did you know that Java comes with built-in date and time library? This would make your life much easier, and your code much less buggier. See [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) as well as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) for instance.

Answer (score 4):

#### Idiomatic Object Oriented Approach:

> Ignoring that this is a naive strawman problem domain already handled
>   by classes in the JDK as well as JodaTime and other existing
>   solutions, this is intended to be an example of how to eliminate dense
>   and complex `if/else if/else` and `switch` conditions in general.

This implements a variation of the `Strategy Pattern` which is specifically designed for replacing `if/elseif/else` statements that have a high[cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity). It works just as well for narrow domains like this.

This solution leverages the ability for `Enums` to implement `Interfaces` and provide the `Predicate` logic right inside the actual `Month` enum instance. Using the `Predicate` interface instead of a custom `isValidDay()` method also allows for composition or chaining of the `Predicate` with others.

This eliminates all the noisy duplicated `if/else if/else` statements as well allowing you to adhere to the [`DRY Principle`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) as well.

#### [Q34909522.java](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/Q34909522.java)

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;

import com.google.common.base.Predicate;

public class Q34909522
{
    private static enum Month implements Predicate<Integer>
    {
        JANUARY(31),
        FEBRUARY(28),
        MARCH(31),
        APRIL(28),
        MAY(31),
        JUNE(30),
        JULY(31),
        AUGUST(31),
        SEPTEMBER(30),
        OCTOBER(31),
        NOVEMBER(30),
        DECEMBER(31);

        public final int daysInMonth;

        private Month(final int daysInMonth)
        {
            this.daysInMonth = daysInMonth;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean apply(@Nullable final Integer input)
        {
            return input != null && input >= 1 && input <= this.daysInMonth;
        }
    }

    public static void main(@Nonnull final String[] args)
    {
        /** Scanner excluded for brevity */
        for (final Month m : Month.values())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 33; i++)
            {
                if (!m.apply(i))
                {
                    System.out.format("%d is not a valid day of the month for %s (%d)", i, m, m.daysInMonth );
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Outputs:

```
0 is not a valid day of the month for JANUARY (31)
32 is not a valid day of the month for JANUARY (31)
33 is not a valid day of the month for JANUARY (31)
0 is not a valid day of the month for FEBRUARY (28)
29 is not a valid day of the month for FEBRUARY (28)
30 is not a valid day of the month for FEBRUARY (28)
31 is not a valid day of the month for FEBRUARY (28)
32 is not a valid day of the month for FEBRUARY (28)
33 is not a valid day of the month for FEBRUARY (28)
truncated for brevity ...
```

#### Leap Year:

> Enhancing this to determine if `February` is a *leap year* is an
>   exercise for the reader since this is a trivial well documented
>   problem and outside the scope of the requirements as stated in the
>   question, that specifically instructs that *28 in February is valid,
>   29 is invalid*.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few things you could do here, but off the top of my head here are a couple...

1) You only have 3 different cases- 28, 30 and 31 days so you could collapse these down into 3 `if` statements like so:

```
if (day > 30 && (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
    ...
}
```

2) Store the values in an array and do a lookup:

```
int[] daysInMonth = new int[] { 31, 28, 31, etc... };
if (day > daysInMonth[month]) {
    ....
}
```

3) Use the built in time/date functions to handle this for you.

Answer (score 0):

First, create an array with the number of days for every month.

```
int[ ] daysInMonth = { 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
```

Then, compare the value of `day` with the corresponding position in the array :

```
if (day > daysInMonth[month]) {
    System.out.print("This is not a valid day of the month");
}
```

The only extra check left, is to check whether February is a leap year :

```
boolean isLeapYear = (year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0))
```

Comment: If that is the case, I think you do not have to worry. The system will detect the serial down votes and remove it. Everything should be back to normal by tomorrow. If not, you may flag for moderator's attention which the moderator may give a warning to the serial down voter.

Comment: @user3437460 : How exactly can I report / flag serial downvoting?

Comment: Flag any of your post which you suspect being serial down-voted for moderator's attention. You may select "in need of moderator's attention" and write in the textbox for description.

Comment: @user3437460 : Thanks. I'll try that!

Comment: Thanks @JohnSlegers for this. I was curious if there is a way to have an array start at 1 instead of 0? I can just change the months to 0-11 but ideally I'd like to have 1-12.

Comment: @CalumMullen : You can't have an array start at 1, I'm afraid. You can, however, use eg. a `Map` as an alternative to arrays. Read more @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122913/java-associative-array or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961510/java-making-objects-with-key-value-pairs

Answer (score 0):

The Java core libraries already do date parsing.

Feed the text input directly through a SimpleDateFormat with lenient set to false. It will throw an exception for all invalid values.

```
private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd");
sdf.setLenient(false);
try
{
    sdf.parse("2016 " + args[0] + " " + args[1]);
}
....
```

In addition to not reinventing the wheel, this also forces you to explicitly choose the year, which has a major impact on the legality of leap year dates.